# Notification not working for making VOIP calls using QuickBlox Sdk

Tags: ios, swift, voip, quickblox

We are receiving Notification when directly build from Xcode to a mobile device. But when we create an ipa file and install it on mobile device, notification does not work.We are using free version of iOS SDK for QuickBlox.
We have managed to make calls when the app is in foreground. Current we need help with the Notification part, so that the call is shown in the CallKit even when the app is not open

Comment: Hi.. Please check if this helps
https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/1223#issuecomment-663189506

Answer (score 2):

I got solution for above issue. when we create ipa for testing that time select development option don't select Adhoc option.